# Vectorization of a projection in octave/matlab

Tags: matlab, octave, vectorization

In linear algebra, we can project a vector v onto a subspace U by taking an orthonormal basis b(1), b(2), b(3), ... b(n) of this subspace and compute the sum of the scalar products of b and v(i) times the vector v(i), i.e. (v,b(i))*b(i), summed over i.

Let's assume that we've stored the basis vectors in a Matrix `B` such that its rows are the vectors b(1), b(2), ..., b(n).

I've found a way to compute this with a `for` loop:

```
proj = 0
for i=1:n
 proj = proj + (B(i,:)*v)*(B(i,:)');
end
```

Is there a vectorized version of this procedure?

Answer (score 1):

With matrix multiplications:

```
proj = B.'*B*v(:);
```

This gives the same result as your code, as a column vector.

If you need the result as a row vector:

```
proj = v(:).'*B.'*B;
```

Comment: What's the difference between `v` and `v(:)`? What's the behavior of `.'*` ? So far, I came across `.` as 'entrywise'. What's the entrywise transposition?

Comment: `v` here stands for a vector. It might be a row or a column veector. So I use `v(:)` to force it becomes a column vector. And then `v(:).'` is a row vector, because `.'` means transponse (many people think `'` means transpose, but that's _conjugate_ transponse). Lastly, `.'*` doesn't have a special meaning; it's just `.'` (transpose) and then `*` (matrix multiplication)